# Group by rows with null values in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

| DetectedText | Confidence | image_name | ref | all_text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| INY | 73.215164 | 14.jpeg | NaN | NaN |
| 9:36 | 91.633514 | 14.jpeg | NaN | NaN |
| MICKEYD19 | 89.422897 | 14.jpeg | NaN | NaN |
| Ln | 59.588081 | 14.jpeg | NaN | NaN |
| ADULT | 98.488983 | 14.jpeg | 9b01dc1e | NaN |
| Ln | 59.588081 | 15.jpeg | NaN | NaN |
| ADULT | 98.488983 | 15.jpeg | NaN | NaN |

This is what my dataframe looks like and want to group rows into one by `IMAGE_NAME` and merge the contents of `DETECTEDTEXT` into `ALL_TEXT` and keep the `REF` where `REF` has a non-null value and the corresponding `CONFIDENCE` row. If the same image(15.jpeg) has all null values in the `REF` column then want to merge the `DETECTEDTEXT`into `ALL_TEXT`, change the `CONFIDENCE` to Null.

Expected result:

| Confidence | image_name | ref | all_text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 98.488983 | 14.jpeg | 9b01dc1e | INY 9:36 MICKEYD19 Ln ADULT |
| NaN | 15.jpeg | NaN | Ln ADULT |

I tried using groupby for my each requirements individually but the error I get is `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found

Comment: Will 'REF' column contain either string type values and NaN only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

Option#1:

```
df1 = df.sort_values(['IMAGE_NAME','REF'], ascending=False)
df1 = df1.groupby('IMAGE_NAME').agg({'DETECTEDTEXT' : ' '.join , 'REF': 'last','CONFIDENCE':'last'}).reset_index()[['IMAGE_NAME','REF','CONFIDENCE','DETECTEDTEXT']]
df1.loc[df1['REF'].isnull(), 'CONFIDENCE'] = np.NaN
df1.rename(columns={'DETECTEDTEXT':'ALL_TEXT'},inplace=True)
```

Option#2

```
df1 = df.fillna('0')
df1 = df1.groupby('IMAGE_NAME').agg({'DETECTEDTEXT' : ' '.join , 'REF': 'max'}).reset_index()
df1 = df1.merge(df,on=['IMAGE_NAME','REF'], how='left')[['IMAGE_NAME','REF','CONFIDENCE','DETECTEDTEXT_x']]
df1 = df1.rename(columns={'DETECTEDTEXT_x' : 'ALL_TEXT'})
df1['REF'] = df1.REF.replace('0',np.NaN)
```

Both Prints:

```
  IMAGE_NAME       REF  CONFIDENCE                     ALL_TEXT
0    14.jpeg  9b01dc1e   98.488983  INY 9:36 MICKEYD19 Ln ADULT
1    15.jpeg       NaN         NaN                     Ln ADULT
```

Input df:

```
  DETECTEDTEXT  CONFIDENCE IMAGE_NAME       REF  ALL_TEXT
0          INY   73.215164    14.jpeg       NaN       NaN
1         9:36   91.633514    14.jpeg       NaN       NaN
2    MICKEYD19   89.422897    14.jpeg       NaN       NaN
3           Ln   59.588081    14.jpeg       NaN       NaN
4        ADULT   98.488983    14.jpeg  9b01dc1e       NaN
5           Ln   59.588081    15.jpeg       NaN       NaN
6        ADULT   98.488983    15.jpeg       NaN       NaN
```

**Option#1**:
Option#1 is more elegant and came to me after I wrote Option#2. Just sorting the IMAGE_NAMe & 'REF' combo  and using `groupby`.

**Option#2**:
First replacing all NaNs to zeros for ease of calculation,the `groupby` with `'REF' : 'MAX` returns 9b01dc1e for 14.jpeg and 0 for 15.jpeg. Now using `pd.merge`, pick the 'confidence' score corresponding to those REF values. For 14.jpeg, it returns the correct match for 9b01dc1e from original df and for 15.jpeg, it returns NaN since there is no match for 0 in the original df. So we get the required input.

**Note:**
The code may need some changes if you can have multiple not null REF values for the same image. If so, we might have to do some other pre-processing as well. Other than that, this should work.